# handling webclient cookies with C#

Tags: cookies, webclient

I have this code:

```
           string session = "SomeSessionCode";
           WebClient wac = new WebClient();
           wac.Headers["Cookie"] = "pu=1; pk=; sid="+session;
           wac.DownloadFile(url, filepathname);
```

is it correct to use Cookie header like this or i'm doing something wrong?

thanks

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825377/how-can-i-get-the-webclient-to-use-cookies for answers.