# How maintain session beetween two Url in asp. Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-session

I have two URl's . If I open first url it will allow us authentication. Second URL will open web content as XML data. I need to read that data... But when I excute first URL its working fine Authentication is SUCCESS, But immediately I try to open second URL its saying Authentication failed . How to maintain session from first URL to second URL...

My Code :

```
string url1 = "http://172.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/cms?login&username=santhu&password=welcom0e";
string url = "http://172.xx.xx.xx:xxxx//cms?status=ProcessStatus";
string result = null;
string result1 = null;
try
{
  WebClient client = new WebClient();
  result = client.DownloadString(url1);

  TextBox1.Text = result.ToString();
  result1 = client.DownloadString(url);
  TextBox2.Text = result1.ToString();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{           
}
```

Comment: use Session[""] variable to maintain the value or Cookie?

Comment: ok i maintain session values but how to render that session to second url..to know already authenticated..

Comment: Please try to Give solution i am hanged here...

Answer (score 1):

```
private class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
{
    public CookieAwareWebClient(): this(new CookieContainer())
    {
    }
    public CookieAwareWebClient(CookieContainer c)
    {
        this.CookieContainer = c;
    }
    public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; set; }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        if (request is HttpWebRequest)
        {
            (request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = this.CookieContainer;
        }
        return request;
    }
}
```

Otherwise you can solve the problem by adding the values manually by using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for cookies :)

```
webClient.Headers.Add("Cookie", "PHPSESSID=xxxxxxx; mosesuser=xxxxxxx; ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to remember the "Set-Cookie" response header from the first request and send it in your second request.

Basically, after the first request (probably after DownloadString() you would need to find the header in `client.ResponseHeaders`, and then you would need to add it to  `client.Headers` somehow.

EDIT: Seems like the above isn't possible, but you can modify the underlying WebRequest instance, see this question: [How can I get the WebClient to use Cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825377/how-can-i-get-the-webclient-to-use-cookies)

or this: http://couldbedone.blogspot.com/2007/08/webclient-handling-cookies.html

Comment: i tried this(http://couldbedone.blogspot.com/2007/08/webclient-handling-cookies.html) but i unable to understand how to Do can u please help me with this...how to do...