# Do PHP Session variables apply to EXE non-browser applications?

Tags: php, vb.net

I'm working on a game that will use internet PHP with a downloaded EXE client in VB.NET 2010.

Since the downloaded EXE is not a browser, would php be able to start a session with the client or is another route required for authenticating the client for each PHP call?

```
vb.net 2010
php 5.0
MySQL
GoDaddy.com as hosting service
```

Previously closed for not being a question?

alright, let me rephrase it in two separate parts:

Can a vb.net application using WebClient (example:  Using client As New WebClient of Systems.net) maintain a valid PHP Session with a webhost?

(that part is a simple yes or no)

if not, then what is the recommended method for maintaining a session type connection with a vb.net application?

i don't have much hope that you can answer these two questions after seeing that you gave up on and closed the first attempt to ask this before i could even finish my milk run to the store. >:|

Comment: does the client have a cookie jar?

Comment: It is my understanding that sessions do not use cookies. I've learned this in school and here is an article repeating what i've learned http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/10/1/0

is this incorrect?

Comment: That article is full of inaccuracies.  The default implementation for sessions stores the session ID in a cookie.  The only other option is to append a `?session_id=<session_id_here>` to all your URLs once they're logged in.   Needless to say, that method is not preferred

Comment: Also, what school is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP sessions rely on cookies<sup>†</sup>, so as long as the client can work with http cookies, then you'll be fine.

Everything else in the session is handled on the server by PHP, so the client doesn't need to know or worry about it. The cookie is the only thing about the session that the client ever sees.

As for whether the VB.Net WebClient can use cookies... well, a quick google search pulls up plenty of info, which confirms that it can indeed do so -- [this answer here on SO, for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825377/how-can-i-get-the-webclient-to-use-cookies).

<sup>†</sup> *Yes, I'm aware that sessions can also use GET request to maintain state, but that's not ideal; cookies are the way to go.*