# WebClient login and download

Tags: vb.net

Unable to download .csv file after logging in using WebClient

My code looks like

```
Public Class Form1
  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim client As New Net.WebClient
    Dim loginInfo As New Specialized.NameValueCollection
    loginInfo.Add("email", "admin@domain.com")
    loginInfo.Add("password", "12345")
    client.UploadValues("https://www.domain.com/login.asp", "POST", loginInfo)
    client.DownloadFile("https://www.domian.com/report.asp?DataFile=97YD7Z9G55.csv", "report.csv")
  End Sub
End Class
```

instead of actual data file it saves login page as report.csv

I didn't find following link helpful

[Using WebClient to login and download files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660782/using-webclient-to-login-and-download-files?rq=1)

Comment: So you tried the cookie-aware web client used in the answer to that question and… what happened?

Comment: Yes I tried it but no success at all

Comment: That is absolutely unhelpful. What *happened*? How did you try using it?

Comment: I copied the class from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825377/how-can-i-get-the-webclient-to-use-cookies and replaced line#3 of my code with this Dim client As New CookieAwareWebClient

Answer (score 0):

One possible problem is that your login request is not successful. Try to inspect what is returned by the web server when `client.UploadValues` is called. Are you sure the fields are named `email` and `password`?

Comment: Yes email and password are correct field names. It returns login page.

Comment: Is there any error message like `Invalid username or password` or something like this?

Comment: Look at the comment below your question. Are you using cookie-aware web client? When you login a cookie is sent back to your client. The client should send that cookie in every request.

Comment: Yeah but seems like its not logging me in. On the other form I have webbrowser control logged in (i use that to fetch report link from anchor tag) I tried client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, WebBrowser1.Document.Cookie) but no luck :(

Comment: if i navigate webbrowser1 to report's link it shows Download Dialog with Save option which I want to skip actually so I tried approaching WebClient to download report file