# c# WebRequest not returning the required page, possibly a header issue

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I'm writing an app to ensure my website is always up to date with our suppliers products. I can get the categories but not the subs.
Basically a webrequest on "xxxx/products/8-propagation/?sub-category=96" always returns "xxxx/products/8-propagation/". I have used console on firefox to see what headers are sent when browsing, I didn't see anything particular but still emulated.
Is there any way to retrieve php requests from URL's or is this something server side only?
I have tried numerous ways of doing this, all the same result.

Comment: Found the answer, a slightly modified version of [How can I get the WebClient to use Cookies?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825377/how-can-i-get-the-webclient-to-use-cookies/2827021#2827021) did the trick so perhaps this was a cookie issue. Not sure how to close this as it is my first question...

Answer (score 0):

Show us your server side code.  I think, this is problem with your routing in controller.

Comment: The server isn't ours, it's our wholesalers. I'm trying to look for new products to list on our own site which is not http://www.hydrogarden.com. Sorry for not being clear. The wholesale site works just fine (and is nothing to do with me) it is my ability to get the products via C# app that is the issue.