# C# WebClient - Getting an HTML from URI instead of CSV

Tags: c#, csv, webclient, obiee

I'm trying to get a csv file from the following uri using C# WebClient.

```
var copUri ="http://obieebr.banrep.gov.co/analytics/saw.dll?Go&Path=%2fshared%2fSeries%20Estad%c3%adsticas_T%2f1.%20IBR%2f1.1.IBR_CSV_XML_ultimos_datos&download_type=csv&NQUser=publico&NQPassword=publico"
var client = new WebClient();
var content = client.DownloadString(copUri);
```

When I try it in my browser I get the csv file, but the above code is returning the authentication html file instead. How do I get past this html response to get the csv file?

Comment: Did you try with WebClient.DownloadFile() method instead?

Comment: Looks like on initial hit, it sets some cookies.  You'll need to use a cookie-aware client, visit the URI, then visit the same URI again.  Only on the second time, will it give you the CSV.

Comment: You are downloading the report from the Oracle BI which is very heavy session aware and like @Kyle pointed out sets some session cookies such as `ORA_BIPS_LBINFO` and `ORA_BIPS_NQID` on the very first request. I am not familiar with Oracle BI, but perhaps you can ask this question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/obiee.

Comment: Tried to use the following cookie-aware webclient (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825377/how-can-i-get-the-webclient-to-use-cookies), but the problem still remains..

Answer (score 0):

You have pass Authorization credentials with uri.

Server rejected your request due to un-authenticate activity.

Comment: The "...&NQUser=publico&NQPassword=publico"  part in the URI would not enough to pass authentication?

Comment: They ave applied token base authentication you should required token for authorization. 
Please try first in postman, ARC or any other client application.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was beyond the cookie awareness - the csv was compiled with javascript in the browser. Solved by using Casperjs to render the obfuscating javascript and then getting the data from the underlying instance.